# OneToOne + No Foreginkey + Unidirectional + Datamissing => EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, one-to-one

From a legacy system, we have 1 table (Entity) and 1 view (UserDetail) with no constraints but with relations.

```
Entity
| Id | Desc | Created_By |...

UserDetail
| UserId | F_Name | L_Name |...
```

CreatedBy has the userid of the user who created that entity. We have a unidirectional mapping in Entity.java like below.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
private UserDetail createdBy;
```

**Problem**

But since its a legacy system, we don't have control on that and an user is hard deleted.

When the entityReposity.findAll is called, following error is thrown

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com...UserDetail with id 92237; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com...UserDetail with id 92237
```

**Question**

How to make the JPA consider this association is optional or is there any way in JPA to make it ignore (like @NotFound in Hibernate)?

**Tried**

1. @NotFound works, but we need to hack @OneToOne as @ManyToOne. Also we want an implementation independent solution.
   Noticed this bug too, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-725
2. optional=true  -  If this would have worked as per the syntactical meaning on how it should behave, I wouldn't have written this.
3. Also tried the postLoad() in UserDetails.java.
4. [@PostLoad solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261579/how-solve-javax-persistence-entitynotfoundexception-with-jpa-not-by-using-notf) We have aop exceptionhandler and exception is caught there before @PostLoad in Entity class gets called.

In Entity.java

```
    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad(){
        try {
            System.out.println(this.getCreatedBy()); //Before control comes here, it goes to aop exception handler
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException e){
            setCreatedBy(null);   
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was wrong with the optional=true?  could you print out the query Hibernate generates if you have that set?  I've used optional=true on OneToMany relationships before just fine.  Another possibility you might want to try is using JoinColumn, and nullable = true

Comment: optional=true didnt do anything, no errors. will look for the code base and try to get the query.

Comment: could you post your persistence.xml? (at least the part needed for your presented domain)... Moreover: What version of JPA are you using or "bound" to use?

Comment: Add an attribute  inverse = "false" . it will make  relation unidirectional and will never  try to fetch record from UserDetail table.

Comment: Do you load that object with Session.load or with a JPQL query ? Some annotations or parameters only work when loading an object via its ID.

Answer (score 3):

As crazy as it sounds, you need to make the `@OneToOne` association `optional = false`. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987638/hibernate-one-to-one-lazy-loading-optional-false)  for an explanation.

So the code for the association would be:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
private UserDetail createdBy;
```

Of course the trouble is that if you try to access the associated `createdBy` association, then Hibernate will try to lazy-load the associated Entity and you will get the same exception.

The `@NotFound` is really your best bet.